# Can AWS code deploy update an existing AutoScalingGroup's Launch Config? Or Create a new AutoScalingGroup with a new LaunchConfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, infrastructure

We are currently testing potential processes to implement Blue-Green deployment on AWS by creating new GREEN AutoscalingGroup and swapping that with the old BLUE AutoScalingGroup.

We noticed code pipeline has a nice orchestration feature that could organize the build, test, and deployment.

One of the options in the deployment step is to use CodeDeploy. The way I understand it is, it applies changes to existing ec2 instances by running commands via the "revision". However, I believe this process does not coincide with our Blue-Green deployment plans.

I'm thinking I might have missed something about it. So I thought to ask here. 
Can code deploy be used on my scenario?

If not, can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

At the re:Invent conference (December 2016), native support for blue/green deployments was demoed as a beta feature. There seems to be an additional "Deployment type" property of the deployment group. For a blue/green-type deployment, CodeDeploy will provision new instances, install your application on it, and then re-route the traffic to them.

According to the presenter, current CodeDeploy customers can apply for the beta test. Watch the conference talk on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/bSXRF1poE8g?t=29m17s).